# Examples of Witt decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, quadratic-forms

I am trying to understand the Witt decomposition theorem. In particular, I am looking to find the hyperbolic part of a quadratic form. I am able to find the Witt index of a general diagonal quadratic form, so I know the dimension of the hyperbolic part, but I was wondering if there is some sort of algorithm to find this part for any general quadratic form?

To understand Witt’s theorem, I have been attempting to explicitly decompose some examples of **rational** quadratic forms into their anisotropic, radical and hyperbolic parts, but I have been struggling. For example, I know that the quadratic form $$x^2 + y^2 - 2z^2$$ has a Witt index of 1. How would I write this as a direct sum of hyperbolic and anisotropic quadratic forms? Is there a general way of doing this for $$\sum_{i=1}^N n_i x_i^2 - \sum_{j=1}^M m_i y_i^2$$? Are there any particular cases that are easier to analyse, e.g. when the sums of the coefficients are equal (as in the first example)?

Any help and/or recommended reading would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Witt decomposition is very non-unique; there is no *unique* hyperbolic part unless your form is hyperbolic. To find **a** maximal hyperbolic subspace, you'll want to find non-radical isotropic vectors and start pairing them up. From here I will just say *null* to mean non-radical isotropic. Specifically:

1. Find a null vector $\nu_1$.
2. Find a null vector $\eta_1$ such that $B(\nu_1, \eta_1) \ne 0$ where $B(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the bilinear form associated to your quadratic form.
3. Repeat from step (1) but restricting yourself to the orthogonal complement of $\{\nu_1, \eta_1\}$.

This process will yield null vectors $\nu_1, \nu_2, \dotsc, \nu_w$ and $\eta_1, \eta_2, \dots, \eta_w$ with $w$ the Witt index and $B(\nu_i, \eta_i) \ne 0$ but $B(\nu_i, \eta_j) = 0$ for $i \ne j$. The spaces $W = \mathrm{span}\{\nu_1,\dotsc,\nu_w\}$ and $W' = \mathrm{span}\{\eta_1,\dotsc,\eta_w\}$ are complementary fully-isotropic subspaces and $W \oplus W'$ is a maximal hyperbolic subspace.

Alternatively, we could follow the following process:

1. Find $e_1$ and $f_1$ such that $q(e_1) = -q(f_1)$ and $B(e_1, f_1) = 0$ where $q$ is our quadratic form.
2. Repeat from step (1) but restricting to the orthogonal complement of $\mathrm{span}\{e_1, f_1\}$.

This process is equivalent since we can take $\nu_1 = e_1 + f_1$ and $\eta_1 = e_1 - f_1$, or similarly $e_1 = \nu_1 + \eta_1$ and $f_1 = \nu_1 - \eta_1$. Both methods have tradeoffs: in the first method, finding null vectors is easy, but finding non-orthogonal null vectors may be difficult; in the second method, finding orthogonal vectors is easy, but finding orthogonal vectors with opposite magnitudes may be difficult if your field doesn't have square roots.

For your example quadratic form
$$
  q(x, y, z) = x^2 + y^2 - 2z^2,\quad B(x_1, y_1, z_1, x_2, y_2, z_2) = x_1x_2 + y_1y_2 - 2z_1z_2
$$
we see that
$$
  e_1 = (1, 1, 0),\quad f_1 = (0, 0, 1).
$$
are orthogonal and have opposite magnitudes. Since you know the Witt index is 1 then you know we're done and that $\mathrm{span}\{e_1,f_1\}$ is a maximal hyperbolic subspace.

---

Here is a third method: if we find an anisotropic subspace $K$ with codimension $2w + r$ where $r$ is the radical dimension, then $K^\perp = H\oplus R$ where $H$ is hyperbolic and $R$ is the radical. This follows from the Witt decomposition theorem and because $K\cap K^\perp = \{0\}$ for such a subspace. For your example $2w + r = 2$, so **every** non-isotropic vector gives us a maximal hyperbolic subspace. So every $v = (x, y, z)$ with
$$
  q(v) = x^2 + y^2 - 2z^2 \ne 0
$$
gives $\{v\}^\perp$ as a maximal hyperbolic subspace.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you have any references for this that you could recommend?

Comment: @scqueen My answer above is just applying the definition of "hyperbolic" directly, so I don't have a reference specifically for that. A nice book on quadratic forms and their orthogonal groups is *Classical Groups and Geometric Algebra* by Larry Grove.

Comment: This may be a very stupid question but what does the quadratic form actually LOOK like in this basis? For some reason I can’t get it into the form $(u^2-v^2) + a*w^2$, for some constant a and transformed variables u,v,w.  I thought that the quadratic form could be written like this since this is the direct sum of a hyperbolic and anisotropic part— am I wrong, or have I missed something obvious? If I work over the reals, I can see that I can rescale z to z/sqrt(2), but since I am working over the rationals, I was thinking that this isn’t an appropriate transformation? What have I missed?

Comment: @scqueen The rational case is much more difficult exactly because not all square roots exist. But in this particular case we have $e_1, f_1$ and all we need now is to find a vector $g$ orthogonal to both, say $g = (-1,1,0)$. Now if $v = xg + ye_1 + ze_2$ then we see $$q(v) = 2x^2 + 2y^2 - 2z^2 = 2(x^2 + y^2 - z^2).$$ More generally if we have $\{e_i, f_i\}_{i=1}^w$ then we can extend this to a full orthogonal basis with Gram-Schmidt.

Comment: I don't see any reason why the partlcular form with $u^2 - v^2$ would always be possible, but a multiple of this should always be possible.

Comment: What is $e_2$ in this case? Do you mean $f_1$?

Comment: @scqueen Sorry, yes, that was a typo.

Comment: And one more thing to clarify: by orthogonal, do you mean that $B(g, e_1) = B(g, f_1) = 0$? Or just using the ordinary dot product? (I picked an unfortunate example here where the vectors are orthogonal under both definitions...)

Comment: @scqueen The associated bilinear form $$B(v,w) = \frac12(q(v+w)-q(v)-q(w)).$$